# Validate string to have only one occurrence of `-` or `.` special characters inside it

Tags: c#, regex

I have a scenario where I need to validate given string which only be allowed to have `-` or `.` special characters in the middle of the given string.

1. It cannot have `-` or `.` special characters at the beginning or end of the string.
2. either `-` or `.` are allowed in a given string, not both of them at same time (at most one occurrence allowed).
   I used Regex to validate given string.

`Regex regex = new Regex(@"(^[a-zA-Z]+[.|-]?([a-zA-Z]+)$)");`
and validating string passing into `IsMatch` method
`regex.IsMatch(givenString)`

Above is the solution I came up with. Is there a better way to validate this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work? What is wrong with it that you want to make "better"?

Comment: You can use `^[a-z]+[.-]?[a-z]+$` with case insensitive modifier. P.S. No need to put `|` in a set, it'll be interpreted literally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current regex does not allow a single char input while it is possible to have `a`. You may fix it using a grouping construct with a `?` quantifier set to it:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[.-][a-zA-Z]+)?$");
// or, using the case insensitive modifier
var regex = new Regex(@"^[A-Z]+(?:[.-][A-Z]+)?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `(?:[.-][a-zA-Z]+)?` - one or zero repetitions of `.` or `-` followed with 1 or more ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string (or `\z` in case you do not want to allow a match before a trailing `\n`).

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5ba-zA-Z%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5b.-%5d%5ba-zA-Z%5d%2b%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=a%0d%0aAb%0d%0aAb.Ty%0d%0ag-te%0d%0aAc-ry.y%0d%0aAc.ry.y%0d%0aAs-.ff%0d%0aGhr..r%0d%0adfg.%0d%0a-ghj&o=m).

Comment: This still fails rule #2 in the question.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn *2. either `-` or `.` are allowed in a given string, not both of them at same time.* - they are allowed due to `[.-]` and the `*` quantifier (so, `.` and `-` can be there but cannot follow each other due to `[A-Z]+` inside the parentheses requiring at least one letter between the symbols).

Comment: I interpret the requirement as he's parsing something like a phone number, where either `555-555-1234` or `555.555.1234` are considered valid, but not `555-555.1234`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That is not a requirement here. For such cases, there is usually no need to define unlimited number of `./-+letters` repetitions, the number of groups is usually set and `([.-]).....\1` would solve the problem.

Comment: I just updated #2, Your answer still breaks #2. Since the given string can only have one occurrence of the specified special characters.

Comment: @ivj Now, it reads *either - or . are allowed in a given string, not both of them at same time (at most one occurrence allowed)* - see the update, it turned out much easier.